# Best way to move date/textures from CLR to Runtime Component for directx when doing Win Store Apps

Tags: c#, directx, windows-store-apps, textures

I have a Windows Store App, and A Runtime Component (Cpp/CX) that creates SurfaceImageSource (direct3d rendering).

The app shows a gridview of images. When a user click an image, i want to use it as a texture in my RT library. What are my options and what are best. Should i pass the path to the image to the RT Lib and load it somehow there or should i load it in CLR and pass over the data as a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the filename might crash due to the security restrictions of Windows Store Apps. You can open a file only with a file picker or if you have been granted the explicit permission.

So when loading the file, you should save its content. E.g. to a byte array. Here is how the byte array can be generated from a `StorageFile`:

```
//file is the input StorageFile
var sourceStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
//do anything else with the file, e.g. creating a BitmapImage
using(MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Reset the file stream
    sourceStream.Seek(0);
    sourceStream.AsStreamForRead().CopyTo(mem);
    var bytes = mem.ToArray();
}
```

Then you should pass the byte data to the DirectX library and load it to a texture. Alternatively you can use the `BitmapDecoder` class to convert the file to raw image data. The methods `CreateAsync`, `GetPixelDataAsync` and `DetachPixelData` might be of help.